# how to install Xmlrpc in Joomla and work it with c#?

Tags: c#, joomla, xml-rpc

i want to set xmlrpc in joomla and work it with c#
can i use JoeBlogsV1 for joomla ? or this is just use only for wordpress ?
how can i do it ?(intsall xmlrpc in joomla and working it with my c# application?)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has XML-RPC built in by default; it's also disabled by default.  You'll have to look into the plugins on your Joomla site to find/enable it (but it is there).

I never had much luck with it however and found myself having to use an external extension to get properly connected via xml-rpc.  You can check out the [Social Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition) to see if there's something there that may help you on your way if the default/stock Joomla xml-rpc doesn't perform admirably for you.